# Reorganizing a dataframe in R by columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-structures

I'm new to coding and I don't really know what to google/search for because I can't find a fitting name for this operation. I'm sorry if I phrased the question poorly, I'm still unfamiliar with the correct terms. 
Regarding my problem: I have a dataset which is structured like following:

```
plant <-  c("A", "B", "C", "D")
employee <- c("Peter, Mark", "Mark", "Peter", "Steven")
df <- data.frame(plant, employee)

  plant    employee
1     A Peter, Mark
2     B        Mark
3     C       Peter
4     D      Steven
```

I now want to "reorganize" the dataframe by employee so it looks like so:

```
  employee plant
1    Peter  A, C
2     Mark  A, B
3    Maria     A
4   Steven     C
```

I'm really helpless as where to look for directions or a solution, I would appreciate any hint.
Is this possible in base R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` to split the 'employee', column, then grouped by 'employee', `paste` the 'plant'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(employee) %>%
  group_by(employee) %>% 
  summarise(plant = toString(plant))
```

---

If we need to use `base R`, an option is to split the 'employee' column with `strsplit` into a `list` of `vector`s, set the names of the `list` with 'plant' column, convert the named `list` to a two column data.frame with `stack` and use `aggregate` to do a group by `paste` (`toString` -  `paste(..., collapse=", ")`)

```
aggregate(ind ~ values, stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$employee),
            ",\\s*"), df$plant)), toString)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this does exactly what I want! 
I understand that packages make things easier, I'm still curious though: how would one solve this in base R?

Comment: Thanks again for the edit. You certainly answered my question already but I do not fully understand the base R line yet. What does  "ind ~ values" do exactly?

Comment: @Wolke The `stack` returns a two column data.frame with 'ind', 'values' as the column names.  In `aggregate` you can use a formula method with the unquoted column names, where 'values' would be the grouping variable

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, we can split the `employee`'s on `","` and repeat the `plant` values based on it. We can use `tapply` to combine `plant` values for each `employee`.

```
temp <- strsplit(df$employee, ",", fixed = TRUE)
stack(tapply(rep(df$plant, lengths(temp)), trimws(unlist(temp)), toString))


#  values    ind
#1   A, B   Mark
#2   A, C  Peter
#3      D Steven
```